# php image upload extension

Tags: php, image, upload

I have a script to upload a image.. It works fine and gives the image the name image1.png.

The problem i'm facing now is that I can only upload png images and I need to be able to upload all kinds of images. 
I know I have to get the ext. but I can't get it to work.

Here is the script

```
<?php $target_dir = "images2/"; 
$target_file = $target_dir . ("image1.png");
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
} // Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";}}
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to test for OR, not AND when checking your file formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be better to test to see if the image extension is in an array. Shorter code, less problems:

```
$imgExt = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
if(!in_array($imageFileType, $imgExt)) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

[PHP `in_aray()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove below piece of code from your uploading script

```
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```

and set `$uploadOk=1;` or no need to set it.

Might be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

in that if condition u can use only the following condition

```
 if($imageFileType != "png"  ) {
     echo "</br>Sorry, only  PNG files are allowed.";
     $uploadOk = 0; }
```

Comment: OP wants *all* of the image types to be allowed.

Comment: use this code                                                                                  if($imageFileType != "jpg" || $imageFileType != "png" || $imageFileType != "jpeg"
|| $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:
`if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png" || $imageFileType == "jpeg" || $imageFileType == "gif" ) {`

And remove `$uploadOk`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the extension of uploaded file for the target file:

The $target_file variable doesn't contain the extension:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . ("image1.");
```

It gets added at the end:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file.$imageFileType)) {
```